# How to transform the problem into convex optimization problem?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$maximize: -\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^{m}_{j=1} f_{ij}·p_j+\sum^{n}_{j=1}\tilde{f_i}·\tilde{p_i}$

subject to:
$1^{T}c_j=1^T\tilde{c_i}=1\\\tilde{c}^{min}\leqslant\tilde{c_i}\leqslant\tilde{c}^{max}\\\sum^{n}_{i}f_{ij}\leqslant F_j \ (0\leqslant f_{ij},0<F_j)\\\tilde{f_i}\leqslant\tilde{F_i}\\\sum^{m}_{j=1}f_{ij}·c_j=\tilde f_i·\tilde{c_i}$

and the $f_{ij} \ \tilde{f_i} \ \tilde{c_i}$ here are the variables, the rest are known.

I have no idea how to deal with this part.. $\sum^{m}_{j=1}f_{ij}·c_j=\tilde f_i·\tilde{c_i}$

Comment: $c_j$ is not a variable?

Comment: Yeah it's not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give many sign restrictions, but let me assume that every parameter and variable is nonnegative. You can replace all occurences of $\tilde{c_i}$ with $\left(\sum^{m}_{j=1}f_{ij}·c_j\right) / \tilde f_i$, and then multiply each constraint with the denominator to make them linear again.

Comment: Thank you! I think that will do

Comment: @XJY95 Why not upvote then.

Comment: Sorry, the upvote from users with scores lower than 15 does not count...